# Separating 3-cliques in DBHT clustering

Tags: graph-theory

this post will have some python code, but the heart of the question is math, not coding. I've been reading about what makes a clique "separating" in a planar maximally filtered graph. This article https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.4477 says, in the beginning of the methods section (pg 12 of the pdf) that "if we detach from the graph the vertices belonging to a separating cycle **then two disjoint and non-empty subgraphs are produced**. The simplest cycle is the3-clique which is a key structural element in PMFGs. An example of PMFG is shown in Fig.6 where the separating 3-cliques are highlighted." Here are the separating cliques he highlights, and the full graph.[image]

So I figure I'll verify that. I replicate this graph in python, making sure to display it as planar.

```
gee = nx.Graph()
gee.add_nodes_from([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
gee.add_edges_from([(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5),(2,7),(2,9),(3,4),(3,6),(3,8),(3,9),(4,5),(4,6),(4,7),(4,8),(5,6),(5,7),(5,9),(6,8),(6,9)])
nx.draw_planar(gee,with_labels = True)
plt.show()
```

It produces this:
[image]

Now I remove what the author calls k1, vertices 2, 3 and 4.

```
gee.remove_nodes_from([2,3,4])
nx.draw_planar(gee,with_labels = True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

So we can see that vertex 1 is by itself, it looks like an empty subgraph. k2 and k3 are similar, stranding vertexes 7 and 8, respectively. I'm wondering how this can be when the author says that removing the separating 3-cliques leaves us with two non-empty subgraphs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A $3$-clique is separating if there are two disjoint and non-empty **sets of vertices** that are disconnected by the removal of the triangle. In the diagram, $\{1\}$ and $\{5,6,7,8,9\}$ are both non-empty sets, so $\{2,3,4\}$ is a separating $3$-clique. By contrast, $\{1,2,3\}$ is not a separating $3$-clique, because the remaining vertices $\{4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ remain connected when $\{1,2,3\}$ are deleted.

The definitions are meant to capture an intuition behind what a separating $3$-clique is: it's a triangle such that part of the graph is "inside" the triangle and part of the graph is "outside" the triangle. When unsure, rely on that intuition when trying to interpret what technical parts of the definitions mean.